# Limits in $\mathbf {Set}$

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation, limits-colimits

I'm a little confused by this example from [Leinster's book](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf):

[image]

The $x_I$, I suppose, are strictly speaking arrows $x_I: \{\ast\}=1\to D(I)$, and he identifies them with elements of $D(I)$ -- is that right? (If this is so, this part looks okay to me.) But then he says that the set in (5.16) is a limit in Set with projections $p_J(x_I)=x_J$. Aren't $x_J$ themselves projections? The notation $p_J(x_J)$ suggests that $x_J$ are elements of $1=\{\ast\}$ (since $p_J:1=\{\ast\}\to D(J))$ but there is only one element of $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of your question concerns the isomorphism 
$$ \{ \text{cones on $D$ with vertex $1$} \} \cong \{ (x_I)_{I\in \mathbf I} \mid x_I\in D(I)\, \forall I\in\mathbf I \text{ and } D(u)(x_I) = x_J\, \forall u:I\to J \text { in } \mathbf I\}$$

Indeed, the isomorphism maps a cone $(1,(f_I)_{I\in{\mathbf I}})$, which formally consists of morphisms $f_I : 1 \to D(I)$ for all $I\in\mathbf I$ such that $D(u)\circ f_I = f_J$ for all $u:I\to J$ in $\mathbf I$, to the tuple $(f_I(\ast))_{I\in \mathbf I}$ where $\ast$ denotes the single element of $1$. This tuple is indeed in the right-hand side set because of the conditions imposed on the $f_I$s.

In the second part of your question, you are mistaken in thinking that $p_J: 1 \to D(J$). Let us call $L$ the set on the right-hand side above for simplicity. Leinster is trying to prove that $L$ is the vertex of a limiting cone on $D$, so he needs to provide the "legs" of the cone, for which he proposes $p_J : L \to D(J)$ that maps an element of $L$, necessarily of the form $(x_I)_{I\in\mathbf I}$, to the element $x_J$ in $D(J)$. Notice that he does not claim (and indeed he shouldn't!) that he proved that $L$, together with these $p_J$s, is indeed a limiting cone. He refers to a (future?) exercise for that.

Comment: Happy to upvote your answer. Minor quibbles, though: $1).$ The [use of the apostrophe](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/506979/apostrophe-to-indicate-the-plural-of-a-mathematical-object) in $p_J's$ is incorrect and confusing. $2).$ "you are mistaking in thinking" is incorrect. It should be "you are $\textbf{mistaken}$ in thinking". $3).$ "Remark that" is also incorrect English. I only point out these minor errors because you seem to be quite strict about writing "MSE aceptable" answers. Cheers.

Comment: @Matematleta Thanks. As you can guess, English is not my primary language, and this kind of pointers are welcomed! I'll edit right away.

Comment: @Pece Not to beat this to death, but I’ve noticed this usage in many Francophone writers. It seems that “remarquer” translates either as “to remark” or “to note”. The first person plural forms “we remark/we note” are essentially synonymous, both translating “nous remarquons”, but the imperative forms “note that/remark that” are not, as the latter seems to be requiring the reader to note something *verbally*.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Ok, so what would be the correct version? Is "notice" better or does it have the same implied meaning of "verbal notification"? Or maybe I shouldn't use the imperative form at all in this context?

Comment: @Pece “Note” works perfectly. Sorry if I seemed to imply otherwise. “Notice” is also good.

Comment: @Pece I only meant that I think we should exercise a bit of common sense and civility when posting here. When it comes to proof-writing, no one has the market cornered on perfection. I know more than a few people who won't post to MSE, because of the snark and harshness that seem all-too pervasive. When I post, my rule of thumb is: don't write anything you wouldn't say face to face in exactly in the same way. Btw: English is not my first language, either.

Comment: Does the equivalence sign that Leinster uses mean "bijection"? Or does it mean something else?

Comment: @user634426 Yes, it means bijection here. (Actually, there is slightly more here because the bijection is natural in $D$, but it does not matter for the argument here.)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easier to see this in a slightly different way: you have a diagram $D:I\to Set$ and want to propose a candidate $(X,\lambda_i)$ for the limit. We must have $Du(\lambda_i x)=\lambda_jx$ for $x\in X$ and $u:i\to j$ and the cone must satisfy the universal property of limit.

Since for each $i\in I,\ D(i)$ is a set and $\lambda_i$ is an arrow from $X$ to $D(i)$, it makes sense to take $X=\prod_{i\in I}D(i)$ because there are obvious maps from the product to the individual factors: the projections $(x_i)_{i\in I}\mapsto x_i$. These will then be the $(\lambda_i)_{i\in I}$. But there is a condition on the product: it must satisfy $Du(\lambda_i x)=\lambda_jx$. So, we take $X$ to be the set of tuples $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ that satisfy the condition. That is, $X=\{(x_i)_{i\in I}:(\lambda_i x)=\lambda_jx\ \forall\ u:i\to j\}$, and this is Lenister's result.

Of course, you need to show that if $(Y,\alpha_i)$ is another cone to $D$, then there is a unique $\phi:Y\to X$ such that $\lambda_i\circ \phi=\alpha_i$ for all $i\in I$. But this is easy. Set $\phi(y)=(\alpha_i(y))_{i\in I}$ and check that this is the required arrow.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the equality $X=\prod_{i\in I} x_i$. It looks like $x_i\in D(i)$. But then the product of all $x_i$ is a tuple (not a set). How can it be equal to the set $X$?

Comment: The more general definition of the product is via choice functions $f:I\to \bigcup_{i\in I}D(i)$ s.t.$f(i)=x\in D(i)$ The collection of all such choice functions is exactly the product. So, you can regard each tuple as a "listing" of the range of a particular choice function.

Comment: So $X$ is $\{\prod_{i\in I} x_i : x_i\in D(i)\}$ rather than $\prod_{i\in I} x_i$? Then how does Leinster get the third (last) isomorphism (= bijection?) in his chain of isomorphisms? I.e. how do the cones on $D$ with vertex $1=\{\ast\}$ correspond to the set of all "listings" $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ satisfying $(Du)(x_i)=x_j$ for all $u:i\to j$?

Comment: Yes, it's the product. The point of this is that by the UMP of the limit, to every arrow $\phi:1\to \lim D$ there is a unique cone $(1,\alpha_i)$ and vice versa. Now, by construction, $\alpha_i$ just picks out an element of $D(i).$ But this is exactly what the projection from the product does, so if we want $\alpha_i$ to satisfy $\lambda_i\circ \phi=\alpha_i$ we are forced to set $\lim D=\prod x_i$ and then the limit cone must be $(\prod x_i,\lambda_i=\text{proj}_i).$

Comment: This answer makes no sense to me. The $x_I$ are **not** tuples: each $x_I$ is a member of the set $D(I)$ (whose elements have no reason to be tuples of any sort). The notation $\prod_{i\in I}x_i$ where the $x_i$ are not sets makes also no sense to me. Moreover $I$ is used as a generic object of $\mathbf I$ by Leinster, I don't understand how it becomes an indexing set in this answer. Yet the answer is upvoted twice, so I might be missing something: please edit and explain your notations and terminology here.

Comment: @Matematleta I am not the OP, and if you look at my answer below, you'll see that I noticed the same thing as you in the question (that OP mistakes the domain of $p_J$ with 1). Btw the domain of $p_J$ is not the product either. My criticism is about the way you write your answer with approximate notations. For example $\prod_{i\in I}x_i$ is **not** another way to write $(x_i)_{i\in I}$: when the $x_i$'s are sets (and some might argue that everything is set in set-theoretic foundations) then both entities exist and are different. [...]

Comment: [...]  And I don't ask you to read Leinster's book (I did not either actually), just to read the question carefully enough so that you use the same notation as the OP in order not to confuse him/her. An answer on MSE has to be 1) correctly written, 2) pedagogical. This is neither of these in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am sorry my answer does not meet your criteria for what a good MSE post should be. Fair point about using the OP's notation. +1. As far as the product notation, it's easily changed. And yes, I have seen it before, but yes I do agree it may be confusing. As far as the $p_j$ being the projections from the product, yes they are, and if you read with attention the OP's pasted text, you will see that the penultimate sentence says this explicitly: "$p_J((x_I)_{I\in \bf I})=x_J$" so the domain of $p_J$ must be a subset of the product, which turns out to be the limit.

Comment: @Matematleta I would argue that these are not "my" criteria but the criteria of MSE's community, but this is probably a sterile debate. On the mathematical content though, I have to insist that the domain of the $p_J$s is not the product, it is the limit itself (which is indeed isomorphic to a subset of the product but it only confuses the beginners if we don't insist of what is the vertex of a cone).

Comment: @Pece Yes, correct. The $p_J$ are projections from a subset of the product, which you'll note I pointed out in my comment. I think Lenister should have just constructed the limit without trying to "motivate it", although I suppose it's a question of style and preference. When I first learned this material (most of which I have since forgotten, argh), I used [Simmons' book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/an-introduction-to-category-theory/38C6B02892C2FE7408F52975756AC88D) before jumping to CWM. Simmons does it carefully, considering choice functions and the condition imposed by the cone.